How to capture incoming audio streams in google meet
I'm trying to build a bot that will capture the incoming video and audio streams from google meetings.
I was using chatgpt to help me with this and I managed to get to the point where I can download the video recordings but no matter what I try, I can't seem to find how/where audio is streamed.
Here is the snipped I used to download incoming video streams:
// Object to store active recorders by stream ID
const recorders = {};

// Override setRemoteDescription method to intercept incoming tracks
const originalSetRemoteDescription = RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setRemoteDescription;
RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setRemoteDescription = async function(desc) {
    const result = await originalSetRemoteDescription.call(this, desc).catch(console.error);
    // Handle incoming tracks
    this.ontrack = (event) => {
        console.log('ontrack event:', event);
        const streamId = event.streams[0].id; // Unique ID for each stream
        if (!recorders[streamId]) {
            // If recorder for this stream does not exist, create a new one
            const recorder = createRecorder(event.streams[0], streamId);
            recorders[streamId] = recorder;
        }
    };
    return result;
};

// Function to create a MediaRecorder and handle recording logic
function createRecorder(stream, id) {
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    const chunks = [];
    recorder.ondataavailable = event => {
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
            chunks.push(event.data);
        }
    };
    recorder.onstop = () => {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = `${id}__${new Date().toISOString()}.webm`;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 100);
    };
    recorder.start();
    return recorder;
}

// To stop all recordings:
function stopAllRecordings() {
    Object.values(recorders).forEach(recorder => {
        recorder.stop();
        delete recorders[recorder.streamId];
    });
}

Any help in this would be amazing, additionally if anyone could point me in a direction where I could learn more about this stuff would also be nice.

It's possible that the audio track isn't being added to the stream. You can verify this by logging the output of stream.getAudioTracks(). If this returns an empty array, it means there are no audio tracks in the stream. or the audio is being muted somewhere? or there might be an issue with the audio codec

@SujalShah, Yes stream.getAudioTracks() is empty, do you know why this could be the case? or what can I do to properly record audio streams as well?

Looking for an answer for this question too. I have a similar use case.
